# Problema com inserção de chave estrangeira no banco Postgres - Elixir/Phoenix

Tags: elixir

Eu sou novo no uso de Elixir e gostaria de fazer uma inserção com chave estrangeira no banco(Postgres), via POST (é um JSON)

abaixo meus módulos

```
defmodule MeuProjeto.Carteiras.Carteira do
  use Ecto.Schema
  import Ecto.Changeset


  schema "carteiras" do
    field :campo_1, :string
    field :campo_2, :integer
    field :moedas_id, :id
    has_one :moeda, MeuProjeto.Moedas.Moeda

    timestamps()
  end

  @doc false
  def changeset(carteira, attrs) do
    carteira
    |> cast(attrs, [:campo_1, :campo_2])
    |> validate_required([:campo_1, :campo_2])
  end
end
```

e

```
defmodule MeuProjeto.Moedas.Moeda do
  use Ecto.Schema
  import Ecto.Changeset


  schema "moedas" do
    field :nome, :string
    belongs_to :carteira, MeuProjeto.Carteiras.Carteira

    timestamps()
  end

  @doc false
  def changeset(moeda, attrs) do
    moeda
    |> cast(attrs, [:nome])
    |> validate_required([:nome])
  end
end
```

no banco, o relacionamento já existe, moeda_id é uma chave estrangeira na tabela "carteiras".

Quando eu faço o POST, retorna este erro, mostrando toda a struct com os campos, e com a mensagem de falta de chave primária:

> struct `%MeuProjeto.Carteiras.Carteira{...}` is missing primary key value

Eu ainda não consegui entender como colocar esta chave primária, achei que só usando o has_one e o belongs_to ele já fazia a associação. Eu também já coloquei dentro do validate_required o campo com a chave estrangeira, mas li que isso pode gerar falhas de segurança, e o erro continuou sendo o mesmo.

**EDIT**
Ok, depois de pesquisar eu entendi qual era o problema.

Primeiro que eu não preciso dessa relação has_one/belongs_to se eu não for utilizar os dados da minha tabela que a chave estrangeira direciona.

E depois que faltou introduzir a função foreign_key_constraint() no meu schema Carteira.

Ficou assim o código final:

```
defmodule MeuProjeto.Carteiras.Carteira do
  use Ecto.Schema
  import Ecto.Changeset


  schema "carteiras" do
    field :campo_1, :string
    field :campo_2, :integer
    field :moedas_id, :id

    timestamps()
  end

  @doc false
  def changeset(carteira, attrs) do
    carteira
    |> cast(attrs, [:campo_1, :campo_2, :moedas_id])
    |> foreign_key_constraint(:moedas_id)
    |> validate_required([:campo_1, :campo_2, :moedas_id])
  end
end
```

No schema Moeda, só removi a linha *has_one :moeda, MeuProjeto.Moedas.Moeda*